# How can I change this Navbar dropdown item to update from "Login" to "Logout" when a user logs in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update my `Navbar` component so that when a user logs in, the navbar dropdown item "Login" changes to "Logout" but I am having issues. I am new to react and JS but learning as I go, so I apologize for any confusion in this question. I have jsx components for my `Navbar`, `Dropdown`, `Footer`, and for each page that a user wants to view which is rendered in my `App.js` file.

Navbar.jsx:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'; 
import './Navbar.css';
import Dropdown from './Dropdown';
import {NavItemsList} from './NavItemsList';
import NavItems from './NavItems';

function Navbar() {
    const [click, setClick] = useState(false); 
    const [button, setButton] = useState(true);
    const [dropdown, setDropdown] = useState(false);

    const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);
    const closeMobileMenu = () => setClick(false);

    const onMouseEnter = () => {
        if (window.innerWidth < 960) {
            setDropdown(false);
        } else {
            setDropdown(true);
        }
    };

    const onMouseLeave = () => {
        if (window.innerWidth < 960) {
            setDropdown(false);
        } else {
            setDropdown(false);
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <nav className='navbar'>
                <div className='navbar-container-whole'>
                    <div className='left-nav-container'>
                        {/* Link in react-router-dom essentially replaces a tag.*/}
                        <Link to='/' className='navbar-logo'>
                            <img src='/images/logo.png' className='hashtek-logo' alt='logo' />
                            <h1 className='navbar-name'>HashTek</h1>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                    {/* .navbar-container will create a div with that class name. */}
                    <div className='center-nav-container'>
                        <form action='./' method='get' id='search-form'>
                            <div class='searchbar'>
                                <input
                                    class='searchbar_input'
                                    type='search'
                                    name='search'
                                    placeholder='Search..'
                                />

                                <button type='submit' class='searchbar_button'>
                                    <i class='material-icons'>search</i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div className='right-nav-container'>
                        <ul className={click ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
                            <div className='text-links'>
                                {/* This line above is for when you are on mobile, and an item is clicked, the nav menu will disappear */}
                                {NavItemsList.slice(0, 4).map((menu, index) => {
                                    return <NavItems items={menu} key={index} />;
                                })}
                            </div>
                            <div className='logo-links'>
                                {NavItemsList.slice(4, 6).map((menu, index) => {
                                    return <NavItems items={menu} key={index} />;
                                })}
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                        <div className='menu-icon' onClick={handleClick}>
                            <i className={click ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </>
    );
}

export default Navbar;
```

NavItemsList.js:

```
export const NavItemsList = [
    {
        title: 'Products',
        path: '/products',
        cName: 'nav-links',
    },
    {
        title: 'Stats',
        path: '/stats',
        cName: 'nav-links',
    },
    {
        title: 'Contacts',
        path: '/contacts',
        cName: 'nav-links',
        subNav: [
            {
                title: 'About',
                path: '/contacts/about',
                cName: 'dropdown-link',
                menuName: 'contacts-menu',
            },
            {
                title: 'How To',
                path: '/contacts/how-to',
                cName: 'dropdown-link',
                menuName: 'contacts-menu',
            },
            {
                title: 'Developers',
                path: '/contacts/developers',
                cName: 'dropdown-link',
                menuName: 'contacts-menu',
            },
            {
                title: 'Designers',
                path: '/contacts/designers',
                cName: 'dropdown-link',
                menuName: 'contacts-menu',
            },
            {
                title: 'Mentors',
                path: '/contacts/mentors',
                cName: 'dropdown-link',
                menuName: 'contacts-menu',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        title: 'Services',
        path: '/services',
        cName: 'nav-links',
        subNav: [
            {
                title: 'Streaming',
                path: '/services/streaming',
                cName: 'dropdown-link',
                menuName: 'services-menu',
            },
            {
                title: 'Editing',
                path: '/services/editing',
                cName: 'dropdown-link',
                menuName: 'services-menu',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        title: Account,
        path: '/my-account',
        cName: 'nav-links',
        subNav: [
            {
                title: 'Login',
                path: '/login',
                cName: 'dropdown-link',
                menuName: 'account-menu',
            },
            {
                title: 'Profile',
                path: '/profile',
                cName: 'dropdown-link',
                menuName: 'account-menu',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        title: Help,
        path: '/help',
        cName: 'nav-links',
    },
];
```

Dropdown.jsx:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import './Dropdown.css';

function Dropdown(props) {
    const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
    const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);
    const submenus = props.submenus;

    return (
        <ul
            onClick={handleClick}
            className={click ? 'dropdown-menu clicked' : 'dropdown-menu'}
        >
            {submenus.map((subNav, index) => (
                <div className={subNav.menuName}>
                    <li key={index} className='dropdown-links'>
                        <Link
                            className={subNav.cName}
                            to={subNav.path}
                            onClick={() => setClick(false)}
                        >
                            {subNav.title}
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                </div>
            ))}
        </ul>
    );
}

export default Dropdown;
```

NavItems.jsx:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Dropdown from './Dropdown';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

function NavItems(props) {
    const items = props.items;
    const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
    const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);
    const [dropdown, setDropdown] = useState(false);

    const onMouseEnter = () => {
        if (window.innerWidth < 960) {
            setDropdown(false);
        } else {
            setDropdown(true);
        }
    };

    const onMouseLeave = () => {
        if (window.innerWidth < 960) {
            setDropdown(false);
        } else {
            setDropdown(false);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className='link-container' onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}>
            <li className='nav-item'>
                {items.subNav ? (
                    <>
                        <Link
                            className={items.cName}
                            to={items.path}
                            onClick={() => setClick(false)}
                            onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}
                        >
                            {items.title}
                        </Link>

                        {dropdown && <Dropdown submenus={items.subNav} />}
                    </>
                ) : (
                    <Link
                        className={items.cName}
                        to={items.path}
                        onClick={() => setClick(false)}
                    >
                        {items.title}
                    </Link>
                )}
            </li>
        </div>
    );
}

export default NavItems;
```

I am following a tutorial that implements the navbar in their App.js file as follows:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./App.css";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Register from "./components/Register";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Profile from "./components/Profile";
import BoardUser from "./components/BoardUser";
import BoardModerator from "./components/BoardModerator";
import BoardAdmin from "./components/BoardAdmin";
import { logout } from "./slices/auth";
import EventBus from "./common/EventBus";
const App = () => {
  const [showModeratorBoard, setShowModeratorBoard] = useState(false);
  const [showAdminBoard, setShowAdminBoard] = useState(false);
  const { user: currentUser } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const logOut = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(logout());
  }, [dispatch]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUser) {
      setShowModeratorBoard(currentUser.roles.includes("ROLE_MODERATOR"));
      setShowAdminBoard(currentUser.roles.includes("ROLE_ADMIN"));
    } else {
      setShowModeratorBoard(false);
      setShowAdminBoard(false);
    }
    EventBus.on("logout", () => {
      logOut();
    });
    return () => {
      EventBus.remove("logout");
    };
  }, [currentUser, logOut]);
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
          <Link to={"/"} className="navbar-brand">
            bezKoder
          </Link>
          <div className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link to={"/home"} className="nav-link">
                Home
              </Link>
            </li>
            {showModeratorBoard && (
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/mod"} className="nav-link">
                  Moderator Board
                </Link>
              </li>
            )}
            {showAdminBoard && (
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/admin"} className="nav-link">
                  Admin Board
                </Link>
              </li>
            )}
            {currentUser && (
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/user"} className="nav-link">
                  User
                </Link>
              </li>
            )}
          </div>
          {currentUser ? (
            <div className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/profile"} className="nav-link">
                  {currentUser.username}
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                //INTERESTED IN THIS
                <a href="/login" className="nav-link" onClick={logOut}> 
                </a>
              </li>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/login"} className="nav-link">
                  Login
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/register"} className="nav-link">
                  Sign Up
                </Link>
              </li>
            </div>
          )}
        </nav>
        <div className="container mt-3">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path={["/", "/home"]} component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
            <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
            <Route path="/user" component={BoardUser} />
            <Route path="/mod" component={BoardModerator} />
            <Route path="/admin" component={BoardAdmin} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
export default App;
```

From what I can tell, they are checking the state of the `currentUser` and if there is one, then the `Navbar` will be updated to display LogOut and the current user's username. This is where I am having trouble, since I have decided to import an array into my `Navbar` instead. Do I need to change my `Navbar` so that it renders the items in the `Navbar` component directly without the use of the `NavItemsList`, or is there a way for me to check the state and change "Login" to "Logout" without changing my `NavItemsList` component too much? Any help would be appreciated, I have been scratching my head on how to go about this without refactoring my hard work.

Comment: use createContext with useReducer for set state of login
ref: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively

Comment: use a state variable that tells you weather user us logged in, and you can have a ```isUserLoggedIn? 'Logout':'Login'```

Comment: @pavankumar would I need to do that in my NavItemsList.js file since that is where the text is coming from or my Navbar.jsx?

Comment: Sorry if I'm just missing it, but I don't see where the Navbar renders any loging/logout UI or a dropdown.

Comment: @DrewReese it is happening in ```Dropdown.jsx```, they are taking a list from ```NavbarList.js``` and rendering it

Comment: @pavankumar And where is `DropDown` rendered? OP seems to have included a lot of irrelevant code, and is missing relevant code.

Comment: @StephenAranda I would not recommend Navbar to do it, since button is the owner of what to display let the logic also be in the button, just pass on the state to button and let your default title be 'Login' but in the button based on state passed to it write the logic.

Comment: @DrewReese if you closely see ideally the dropdown should have been used in ```Navbar``` component, which is again missing in the question but looks like he is using it in ```NavItem``` component, just an assumption! but OP wanted to understand what minimal changes he needed to achieve the change in 'Login' and 'Logout', hope I addressed it.

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to include how the drop down is rendered which is with NavItem component but it is edited in now. @DrewReese Also, I haven't implemented the UI for logout but I do have login.jsx which I can include if its needed

Comment: @DrewReese In the tutorial I am following, he imports { logout } from "./slices/auth" and EventBus from "./common/EventBus" to implement the logout functionality in his App.js file. However, he also renders his nav items in his app.js whereas I render it through an array. I am not sure if I should have ever done that. I was able to complete the logging in function, but after logging in the navbar of course stays the same since it is an array from NavItemsList.js. So im not sure if I need to change the state somehow in that file or somewhere else

Comment: So am I now understanding correctly that `currentUser` in `App` (*from redux*) is how you know a user is authenticated or not, and you effectively want to toggle the login title and link in the `NavItemsList` config? I suggest you should add an "auth status" property to your links and routing configs so as you are mapping them into the UI you can check the current authentication status and render the appropriate content. I can share an example if necessary.

Comment: @DrewReese yes that is exactly correct! If you could share an example, i would really appreciate it

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't see the edit to your previous comment saying you would like to see an example. Answered below. It avoids coupling your `NavItemsList` data from it's presentation, i.e. there's no explicit `subNav.title==='Login'` check in the UI code since you want it configurable from the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you should add an "auth status" property to your links and routing configs so as you are mapping them into the UI you can check the current authentication status and render the appropriate content.

Example:

```
export const NavItemsList = [
    ...
    {
        title: Account,
        path: '/my-account',
        cName: 'nav-links',
        subNav: [
            {
                title: 'Login',
                path: '/login',
                cName: 'dropdown-link',
                menuName: 'account-menu',
                authenticated: false,
            },
            {
                title: 'Logout',
                path: '/logout',
                cName: 'dropdown-link',
                menuName: 'account-menu',
                authenticated: true,
            },
            {
                title: 'Profile',
                path: '/profile',
                cName: 'dropdown-link',
                menuName: 'account-menu',
            },
        ],
    },
    ...
];
```

...

```
function Dropdown({ submenus }) {
  const { user: currentUser } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => setClick(click => !click);

  return (
    <ul
      onClick={handleClick}
      className={click ? 'dropdown-menu clicked' : 'dropdown-menu'}
    >
      {submenus
        .filter(({ authenticated }) => {
          if (authenticated !== undefined) {
            return !!currentUser === authenticated;
          }
          return true;
        })
        .map((subNav) => (
          <div key={subNav.path} className={subNav.menuName}>
            <li className='dropdown-links'>
              <Link
                className={subNav.cName}
                to={subNav.path}
                onClick={() => setClick(false)}
              >
                {subNav.title}
              </Link>
            </li>
          </div>
        ))
      }
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would Ideally do something like this in the NavItem

```
{subNav.title==='Login'?(userLoggedIn?'Logout':'Login'):subNav.title}
```