# How to create a dropdown menu with submenu in React js app v18

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I'm looking for a way to add submenus to an existing dropdown menu.

Here's what I have already.

**Dropdown.js**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { MenuItems } from './MenuItems';
import "./Dropdown.css";

function Dropdown() {
    const [click, setClick] = useState(false);

    const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);

    return(
        <>
            <ul onClick={handleClick} className={click ? 'dropdown-menu clicked' : 'dropdown-menu'}>
                {MenuItems.map((item, index) => {
                    return(
                        <li key={index}>
                            <NavLink className={item.cName} to={item.path} onClick={() => setClick(false)}>
                                {item.title}
                            </NavLink>
                        </li>
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
        </>
    );
}

export default Dropdown;
```

**MenuItem.js**

```
export const MenuItems = [
    {
        title: 'Beginner',
        path: '/trainingBeginner',
        cName: 'dropdown-link'/*,
        subNav: [
            {
              title: 'Training1',
              path: '/trainingBeginner1',
              cName: 'dropdown-link'
            },
            {
                title: 'Training2',
                path: '/trainingBeginner2',
                cName: 'dropdown-link'
            }
        ]*/
    },
    {
        title: 'Intermediate',
        path: '/trainingIntermediate',
        cName: 'dropdown-link'
    },
    {
        title: 'Advanced',
        path: '/trainingAdvanced',
        cName: 'dropdown-link'
    }
]
```

The text that's in comment in the MenuItem.js file would be the submenus, but adding it like that doesn't work.

**Dropdown.css**

```
.dropdown-menu {
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: start;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
    /*border: 2px solid blue;*/
    background: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-menu li:hover {
    background: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0133FF;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.dropdown-menu.clicked {
    display:none;
}

.dropdown-link {
    /*border: 2px solid red;*/
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 16px;
    color: black;
}

.dropdown-link:hover {
    /*border: 2px solid red;*/
    background: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0133FF;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

This is what it currently looks like:

[image]

I'd like to see the submenus 'Training1' and 'Training2' to pop-up on the right side when hovering over 'Beginner'.

I found a very similar question here: [How can I change this Navbar dropdown item to update from "Login" to "Logout" when a user logs in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71493107/how-can-i-change-this-navbar-dropdown-item-to-update-from-login-to-logout-wh)
But I can't figure out which JS code I'm missing to display the submenus.
I don't understand where item and index are coming from on this line of code `{MenuItems.map((item, index) => {` or how to manipulate it so that submenus also work.

Thank you for sharing any insights that might lead to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a simple explanation of `map` might help you understand your next steps.

> I don't understand where item and index are coming from on this line of code `{MenuItems.map((item, index) => {`

The array function [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is called on an array, and takes a callback function. The callback function is then run when your code runs, by 'javascript itself' (for lack of a better way of describing it) passing three arguments to it: item, index, array.

The Item is each individual *thing* in the array, like in your 'MenuItems' example, you have:

```js
    {
        title: 'Intermediate',
        path: '/trainingIntermediate',
        cName: 'dropdown-link'
    },
```

Index is then the second argument, which is where in the array that *thing* is, starting at 0 for the first thing, then 1 etc. So the item above is *index* 1.

The last argument is the array, which is the whole array (in your case all of 'MenuItems'). It's really rare you need to use it.

The result of calling this callback function, is that each item of the input array is 'mapped' (or 'swapped') onto a new different item in the output array.

```js
const example = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const newArray = example.map((item, index) => index % 2 ? item + 1 : item + 2)

console.log(newArray)
```

---

In your code the callback function the map is calling is changing the *data* into *components*:

```
{MenuItems.map((item, index) => {
   return (
     <li key={index}>
       <NavLink className={item.cName} to={item.path} onClick={() => setClick(false)}>
         {item.title}
       </NavLink>
     </li>
   )
 })}
```

But the only component you're getting here is a single `li` tag with a `NavLink` inside it. You aren't ever asking for it to use `item.subNav` in any way. The linked question seems to not be dynamically generating submenus. You might try something like this:

```
{MenuItems.map((item, index) => {
   return (
     <li key={index}>
       <NavLink className={item.cName} to={item.path} onClick={() => setClick(false)}>
         {item.title}
       </NavLink>
       {item?.subNav && item.subNav.map((subItem, subIndex) => (<SubMenu>Hello I'm SubMenu {subItem.title} and my path is {subItem.path}</SubMenu>)}
     </li>
   )
 })}
```

Or whatever you need to create the submenu items.

Do note my example doesn't show anything about how to get the menus to show on click or hover etc, there are plenty of question here about that, or if none answer your question you can also [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a new one